# What is the default zoom level for Google Earth Engine kernels using the Python API?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, reducers, reduceregion

[The documentation for GEE Kernels](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-kernel-square) states that, " If the kernel is specified in meters, it will resize when the zoom-level is changed." If I am using the python API, however, what is the default zoom-level? And how do I change it?

An example code segment might look something like this

```
kernel = ee.Kernel.euclidean(150000,"meters")
distance = mangrove_map.distance(kernel,false)
reducers = ee.Reducer.mean()
    stats = distance.reduceRegions(
              collection=CensusSectors_aoi,
              reducer=reducers,
              scale=600
              );
```

Where `distance` is some image and `CensusSectors_aoi` is some feature collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Zoom level” is a description that makes the most sense when you're viewing an interactive map. But it's just another perspective on the fundamental concept which is the **requested pixel resolution of the image**.

For example, if you've specified 600 nominal meters per pixel in `reduceRegions()`. Thus, if the kernel were used in that image, it would be

(150,000 meters) / (600 meters per pixel) = 250 pixels

in radius.